# I want to convert Any date format to a UTC European Datetime format

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime

I have researched many forums and stackoverflow question, but unfortunately I didn't find an exact solution for my problem. Guys, can you please give me a solution for my issue.
The issue is this, there are several date formats which I am receiving, so what my concerns is this, need to feed the value to the `def dateconversion(datevalue)` and convert the datetime into a UTC European format. The only problem is the datevalue which gives different types of dateformats like

```
18 March at 20:01
25 February, 2021 22:03:02
13 February at 07:24
13 August 2018 at 16:15
3 May 2018 at 13:13
6 March 2018 at 15:04
12/05/2021 at 21:01:59
12/05/2021  04:19:05
```

The above datevalues will need to process and should give a perfect `%d %B, %Y %H:%M:%S` UTC date and time result. I hope this issue is cumbersome

Comment: Can you add a sample for expected format?

Comment: What is the issue with adding some parsing yourself, along with some pre-existing libraries?

Comment: Look at module `dateutil`. It has a parser that will make as much sense of a string date as it can. That is more convenient than `strptime()` which expects you to know the format of the input date in advance, which you clearly don't. The parser will give you a `datetime` and you can call its method `isoformat()`  to get what you want.

Comment: @RaghavaDhanya I have added

Comment: This is a well-known and poorly defined problem.  To pick an example from your list, is `12/05/2021 at 21:01:59` in March or December?  The best thing to do is take an existing library, do everything automatically that you can, and send the ones you can't to human review.